# Loading google api client library in codeiniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api-php-client

first I copied the Google folder to application/third_party in codeigniter framework.

then google.php inside the application/libraries

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
set_include_path(APPPATH . 'third_party/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/Google/Client.php';

class Google extends Google_Client {
    function __construct($params = array()) {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

and then i have created a controller named googleClass.php

```
<?php
class GoogleClass extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct($params = array()) {
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index(){

    $this->load->library('google');
    echo $this->google->getLibraryVersion();
   }
}
```

But I get the following error...

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='application/third_party/;.;C:\xampp\php\pear') in C:\xampp\htdocs\csvinsert\application\third_party\Google\Client.php on line 18
```

what I'm doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have `autoload.php` in `application/third_party` directory, and rest of the source in `application/third_party/Google` directory.

in the `application/libraries/google.php` remove this line.

```
set_include_path(APPPATH . 'third_party/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

now the code `google.php` will be

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/Google/Client.php';

class Google extends Google_Client {
    function __construct($params = array()) {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

This will get rid of that error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way load your libraries :`include_once APPPATH . "libraries/third_party/Google/Client.php";`