# Adding google api client to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I want to upload files to google drive using php in codeigniter. First of all i am trying to integrate google api client to codiginator.

I have uploaded all the files in to my third_party folder.
 it look like this

[image]

I i have created a file called `google.php` inside my `libraries` folder

**google.php file**

```
        <?php
        if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
        set_include_path(APPPATH . 'third_party/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
        require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/Google/Client.php';

        class Google extends Google_Client {
            function __construct($params = array()) {
                parent::__construct();
            }
        } 

        ?>
```

Then i loaded the library in my home controller like this

```
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

          //session, url, satabase is set in auto load in the config
            $this->load->model('Home_model', 'home');
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $this->load->library('google');

        }
```

After loading the google library none of the functions inside home controllers are working. Every thing just shows a blank page.

And Inside the home controller i have a function 'test_lib'

```
    function test_lib(){

        echo $this->google->getLibraryVersion(); 
   }
```

When i load the page . i get a black page no errors or showing.

Can someone help me to add the google api client library to codeigniter. Tnx.

Comment: Do you have error log enabled? Few things: if CI v3, library file should be capitalized, before path separator, no need to put fore slash.

Comment: Tnx . I am using V 2.2 stable. Error log `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Google_Config' not found in /var/www/html/lankahomes/application/third_party/Google/Client.php on line 80, referer: http://lankahomes.dev/
`

Comment: i Downloaded Google Api Client from this link.. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: Try to require `autoload.php` file from src folder before calling any class in library. It's job would be calling rest of files. If you check in examples, only that file is included before instatiating class objects.

Comment: hehe.. That works, I didn’t notice that one tnx.. can you please add that as a answer, i will accept it..

Comment: I am glad you made it. Also, I want to thank you for asking in such a good way. Very clear question with well provided code and images. Happy coding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned already, following examples in repository, 
`Google/autoload.php` should be included before 
using classes/instantiating objects. In your case it is `APPPATH . 'third_party/Google/autoload.php'` file.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would take an approach of [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134203/loading-google-api-client-library-in-codeiniter?rq=1)  where you create a library file in libraries call it Google.php only that the file to be included is autoload.php instead of Client.php from the response

```
   <?php
   if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
   set_include_path(APPPATH . 'third_party/' . PATH_SEPARATOR .     get_include_path());
   require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/Google/autoload.php';

   class Google extends Google_Client {
      function __construct($params = array()) {
       parent::__construct();
      }
   }
```

And then include it as a normal library in either autoload or every where you want to use the library using

```
 $this->load->library('google');
```

and then echo from somewhere you have loaded the lib

```
     echo $this->google->getLibraryVersion();
```

the output should be something like 1.1.5 etc