# How to configure CreditCard class in Omnipay?

Tags: codeigniter, paypal-sandbox, omnipay

I've been trying to configure Omnipay in CodeIgniter all day long, I think I'm finally cracking it up, but I'm stuck at the credit card validation part. For some reason when I run my I get the error message `Fatal error: Class 'CreditCard' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\trabajo\emarket\application\controllers\inicio.php on line 37`

This is my controller:

```
use Omnipay\Omnipay;

class Inicio extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Pro');

    $gateway->setUsername('######');
    $gateway->setPassword('######');
    $gateway->setSignature('#####');
    $gateway->setTestMode(true);

    $gateway->initialize();

    $cardInput = array(
        'firstName' => 'buyer',
        'lastName' => 'one million',
        'number' => '4032031186341789',
        'company' => 'Visa',
        'billingAddress1' => 'bill me here',
        'billingAddress2' => 'or maybe here',
        'billingPhone' => '4085873015',
        'billingCity' => 'chicago',
        'billingState' => 'illinois',
        'billingPostCode' => '646960',
        'shippingAddress1' => 'ship it here',
        'shippingAddress2' => 'or ship here',
        'shippingPhone' => '98789987',
        'shippingCity' => 'chicago',
        'shippingState' => 'illinois',
        'shippingPostCode' => '989898',
    );

    $card = new CreditCard($cardInput);
}
}
```

Thanks for your time, I'd really appreciate some pointers on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try to add
`use Omnipay\Common\CreditCard`

Comment: @Tpojka thanks so much, that fixed it! Does this mean that everytime I want to call a class I'll have to add it this way to every file I'm working on?

Comment: Usuallly yes. I presume you are using composer and some packages have autoload file that you should include in case having approach to all classes. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284721/adding-google-api-client-to-codeigniter/30285689#30285689).

Comment: Please write comment as an answer and I'll accept it :) And yes, I'm calling the autoload file from index.php  That's why I thought that I wouldn't need to add each class separately. It's not very handy, is it?

Comment: The "company" field is the company that the purchaser represents, not the card issuer. Don't forget also the country needs to be set (US) and the state needs to be the two-character code (IL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are loaded, but you need to point at those. And you are doing that with keyword `use`. Otherwise you could pass something like:

```
$gateway = Omnipay\Omnipay::create('PayPal_Pro');//not quite sure if you need backslash infront of vendor name
```

Or same way you could invoke CreditCard instance:

```
$card = new Omnipay\Common\CreditCard($cardInput);
```

That is reason of having keyword `use`.

[This is good topic source](http://www.php-fig.org/).